# C# XML Десериализация вложенных элементов

Tags: c#, массивы, xml

Здравствуйте. Имеем такой код:

```
public partial class Forecast
{
    [Key]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("location")]
    [XmlArrayItem("day", typeof(Day_))]
    public List<Day_> day { get; set; }
}

public class Day_
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public Symbol_ symbol { get; set; }
    ...
    [XmlArray("day")]
    [XmlArrayItem("hour", typeof(Hour_))]
    public List<Hour_> hour { get; set; }
}

public class Hour_
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
    public Value_ temp { get; set; }
    public Symbol_ symbol { get; set; }
    public Wind_Hour wind { get; set; }
    public Value_ wind_gusts { get; set; }
    public FValue_ rain { get; set; }
    public Val_ humidity { get; set; }
    public Value_ pressure { get; set; }
    public SVal_ clouds { get; set; }
    public Value_ snowline { get; set; }
    public Value_ windchill { get; set; }
}
```

Элементы вложенного массива hour не сериализуются.

Comment: Сам класс как выглядит?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Оказывается нужно более кропотливо описывать структуру XML.
Не было описания для элемента location.
Лучше скопировать XML файл в буфер обмена и вставить его как классы.
Способ нашел на этом сайте.

Comment: если способ описан на этом сайте, добавьте ссылку на решение в ваш ответ